# Drop shadow effect on a Line Graph

Tags: d3.js

I want to have drop shadow effect for the line in my D3 line graph, something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I tried to follow [SVG drop shadows](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_feoffset.asp) but not getting the result as expected.

Here's the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bu9szj?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

And this is the code for the shadow effect:

```
const defs = g.append("defs");
const filter = defs.append("filter").attr("id", "shadow");
filter
  .append("feOffset")
  .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
  .attr("dx", 0)
  .attr("dy", 10)
  .attr("result", "offOut");
filter
  .append("feGaussianBlur")
  .attr("in", "offOut")
  .attr("stdDeviation", 10)
  .attr("result", "blurOut");
filter
  .append("feBlend")
  .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
  .attr("in2", "blurOut")
  .attr("mode", "normal");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a rotated fill gradient instead:

```
const grad = defs
  .append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'grad')
  .attr('x1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '0%')
  .attr('y1', '0%')
  .attr('y2', '100%')
  .attr("gradientTransform","rotate(-45)");

var colors = [ ['rgb(70,130,180)', '1'], ['rgb(70,130,180)', '0'] ];

grad.selectAll('stop')
  .data(colors)
  .enter()
  .append('stop')
  .style('stop-color', function(d){ return d[0]; })
  .style('stop-opacity', function(d){ return d[1]; })
  .attr('offset', function(d,i){
    return 100 * (i / (colors.length - 1)) + '%';
  });

 // ...

// define the area
var area = d3.area()
  .x((d: any) => xScale(d.hrCount) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .y0(height)
  .y1((d: any) => yScale(d.adjCount));

g.append("path")
   .attr("class", "area")
   .attr("d", area(this.graphData))
   .attr("fill", "url(#grad")
```

Produces something like:

[image]

Updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvxk9k)

Comment: This actually helps. Thanks.